# CIImage crash on iOS 13.4.1 simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, thread-safety, ciimage

I'm having a crash on iOS 13.4.1. simulator (only on this one) when initializing CIImage.

When doing
`let image = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)` 
or 
`let image = CIImage(image: uiImage)`
I'm getting
`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

The code looks like this:

```
guard let cgImage = someOptionalUIImageFromModel else { return } // at this point image exists and looks properly in debugger and quick look
let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage) // this is where I get the crash
let transformedImage = ciImage.cropped(to: someRect).transformed(by: someTransform)
```

At first I thought it's a multithreading problem, since I'm creating many CIImages on `.userInitiated` QoS queue, but then I tested it on main thread and still getting the crash.

The same code is working correct on physical devices (both iOS 12 and 13) as well as older simulator versions.

Anyone also encountered it?

Comment: I haven't run into this issue specifically, but I've seen similar things between devices and simulators due to device speed being faster. I'd suggest checking for nil values at various points in the flow (especially if you're URL-based objects). Kind of hard to diagnose without code. If you can narrow it down, post some code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added some code to the question, but I'm not sure if it helps in any way.

Comment: I am experiencing this same problem. I believe the code was working in the simulator in an earlier version of iOS.

Comment: I have the same issue. Consistent crashing in the iOS 13.4.1 simulator on `CIImage(cgImage:)`. It's not reproducible in a test project unfortunately so maybe it depends on the image. In our app it happens with images from `AVAssetImageGenerator`. The exact same code works just fine in an iOS 12.4 sim.

Comment: I experience the same issue (still present in iOS 13.5) I worked around it by using [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageref]; instead which was possible in my case. 

The crash information to me looks like it is a SDK/Simulator bug: 

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 704.12.2 - Device: iPhone X iOS 13 (58D0BF50-53D3-4D4D-8CD8-7D2D5FD6E604) - Runtime: iOS 13.5 (17F61) - DeviceType: iPhone X
XPC API Misuse: Attempt to pass a malloc(3)ed region to xpc_shmem_create().

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is solved in iOS 14 simulator. No crashes with the same code.